# May I know the meaning of *Take some punches*?

Tags: phrase-meaning, british-english

May I know the meaning of *Take some punches*

Comment: Please add more details to your question.  Where did you read this? what is the context?

Answer (score 2):

[ludwig](https://app.ludwig.guru/s/take+a+punch) explains the idiom **take a punch**:

> If somebody takes a blow, something bad happens to them.

> It is often used as a metaphor for someone being able to handle a difficult situation, especially if that situation may involve physical suffering or injury.

*punch* and *blow* are seen to be used interchangeably.

You can use *take some punches* in similar manner.  This usage is quite common, as shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+some+punches+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "to take a punch" (from the domain of fighting and boxing) literally means to be hit with a clenched fist and remaing standing, to not be knocked unconscious by the blow.  As Seowjooheng Singapore remarks, it can be used figuratively to refer to someone being able to continue on, despite setbacks of some kind.

> Your kid is fast on his feet, but can he take a punch?
>
> In the volative world of options trading, you have to be able to take a punch.